# Converting JSON to XML attributes in java

Tags: java, json, xml

I have the following JSON structure :

```
{
   "userId": "55",
   "Unit": [
      {
         "id": "1",
         "unitname": "unit1",
         "eventId": "2",
         "transactiontype": "1"
      },
      {
         "id": "2",
         "unitname": "unit2",
         "eventId": "2",
         "transactiontype": "1"
      },
      {
         "id": "3",
         "unitname": "unit3",
         "eventId": "2",
         "transactiontype": "2"
      }
   ]
}
```

and I need to convert it to the below XMl format :

```
<Units userId="55">

<Unit id="1" unitname="unit1" eventId="2"  transactiontype="1"/>
<Unit id="2" unitname="unit2" eventId="2"  transactiontype="1"/>
<Unit id="3" unitname="unit3" eventId="2"  transactiontype="2"/>

</Units>
```

While trying it through java I ma getting an XML but it shows XML elements as below :

```
<UnitId>1</UnitId>
```

Can someone please help me as to what needs to be done so that I get the XML format needed, i.e as attributes.

Comment: There are many ways of converting JSON to XML and you need to say which one you are using, and how you are using it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the json.org library.
I'm not sure if this library does exactly what you want.

You can use it like that:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
String xml = XML.toString(json);
```

`toString` can take a second argument to provide the name of the XML root node.

XML to JSON using 
`XML.toJSONObject(java.lang.String)`

POM

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20170516</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an XSLT 3.0 solution.

```
<xsl:transform version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template name="main">
  <xsl:variable name="in" select="json-doc('input.json')" as="map(*)"/>
  <Units userId="{$in?userId}">
    <xsl:for-each select="$in?Unit?*"
      <Unit id="{?id}" unitname="{?unitname}" 
            eventId="{?eventId}"  transactiontype="{?transactiontype}"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </Units>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

You can run this from Java by installing Saxon-PE 9.7.